# Has Lord Shiva worshipped Lord Vishnu to incarnate in any form?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, rama, avatars

Which all Gods prayed to Lord Vishnu to incarnate as Lord Rama? Was Lord Shiva also one of them? 
If not, then has Lord Shiva worshipped Lord Vishnu to incarnate in any form?

Comment: Can you correct the grammer in your q? It is currently not understandable.

Comment: I mean, Who all Gods prayed Lord Vishnu to take the avatar of Lord Rama? Did Lord Shiva also pray him?
Is my question clear?

Comment: No sorry, can maybe fix the grammar?

Comment: @Parth Bhagwat Do you mean that was Lord Shiva present among the gods who prayed to Lord Vishnu to incarnate as Rama?

Comment: @Manoj Gowda, Yes!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Lord Shiva was present when the Gods prayed to Lord Vishnu to incarnate as Rama. The verse can be found in the 15th Sarga of Balakana of Valimiki Ramayana. I am reproducinng it from [here](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=15).

> तदा देवर्षि गन्धर्वास्सरुद्रास्साप्सरोगणा:।
>
> स्तुतिभिर्दिव्यरूपाभिस्तुष्टुवुर्मधुसूदनम्।।1.15.31।।
>
> Then along with gandharvas, groups of apsaras, rishis, **rudras** and devatas sang in praise of the 'Lord Slayer of Madhu', with hymns of celestial beauty.

The sloka mentions that Rudras were also present. Since Lord Shiva is the leader of Rudras, we can infer that he too was present.

Lord Shiva was also present when Devatas urged Lord Visnhu to incarnate as Krishna. Slokas can be found in Bhagavatha purana. I am quoting from [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/).

> ब्रह्मा तदुपधार्याथ सह देवैस्तया सह ।
>
> जगाम सत्रिनयनस्तीरं क्षीरपयोनिधे:॥
>
> Thereafter, having heard of the distress of mother earth, Lord Brahmā, with mother earth, Lord Śiva and all the other demigods, approached the shore of the Ocean of Milk.

Comment: Thank you @Manoj Gowda. I had read about the Halebidu Temple "astronaut" thing and saw the sculpture in a image on web. I don't think that it is actually true. I saw some a video on YouTube by "Pravin Indramohan" regarding that. He said that the helmets wore by sculpted Devas and wires around the bodies of the Devas referring to an astronaut suit. But I think that it is "Yadnyopavit"(I don't know English word for it, but maybe "sacred thread") and I guess it's not any helmet but the setting of the hair was like that during those days.

Comment: Also in other sculpts in the same temple, one can see the same hair setting which are depicting different scenarios. Also these Devas are worshipping Lord Vishnu (The sculpt is broken near the head so not sure but some web sources support it by saying that the hand holds "Sudarshan Chakra") and I think that one of the god is Lord Shiva(it's my guess because there's a thing around his neck which I presume is "Vasuki"). Hence I'd asked this question that whether Lord Shiva had worshipped Lord Vishnu or not. I would like to get your views too on the "Astronaut" thing of Halebidu Temple.

Comment: @Parth I visited Halebidu long time back. I do not remember the specific sculpture you are referring to.

Comment: You can see this:  https://images.app.goo.gl/f36kEXf17FD2pjsG8. Also you may read this: http://www.phenomenalplace.com/2017/11/ancient-astronauts-carved-in-halebidu.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

Shiva means "***the auspicious/kind one***". The word Shiva is used as an epithet for several vedic deities, including Rudra.

Like other epithets like Indra, **Vishnu, Rudra**, etc, **Shiva** is an epithet used to indicate the auspiciousness/kindness of the Almighty God.

For example:

In respect of Agni: ([RV I.31.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01031.htm))

> तवमग्ने परथमो अङगिरा रषिर्देवो देवानामभवः ***शिवः सखा*** | तव वरते कवयो
>   विद्मनापसो.अजायन्त मरुतो भराजद्र्ष्टयः ||
>
> You, Agni, the first Aṅgiras, the seer, the god, became a ***kindly
>   comrade*** of the gods. Under your commandment were born the sage poets
>   working with their know-how—the Maruts with glinting spears.

---

It was in the interpolated parts of EPICs and many puranas deified the epithets Vishnu, Rudra, Agni, etc.

So Shiva worshipping Vishnu, for incarnating in some form, if found in Puranas, is the story added at a later date.

---

In Ramayana (Sarga 15 of Bala Kanda), there was a mention of various gods extolling Vishnu.

> तदा देवर्षिगन्धर्वाः सरुद्राः साप्सरो गणाः |
>   स्तुतिभिर्दिव्यरूपाभिस्तुष्टुवुर्मधुसूदनम् || १-१५-३२
>
> Then all the groups of gods, sages, gandharva-s, with rudraa-s, and
>   apsarasa-s, extolled Vishnu with prayers of divine exposition.

---

As mentioned above, there are some interpolated Sargas in Ramayana.  Sargas 15 - 17 of Bala Kanda are one among them.

As far as I read, Understood, Shiva did not pray to Vishnu to incarnate in some form.

Comment: Well said , well said ! Historically speaking , Savism came centuries before the Vishnavites.